# Go to visual states inside a Grid in code behind in Windows Store apps

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

So my xaml code looks like this -

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
```

I can't use the `GoToVisualState` behavior because I need to do some checks before running this animation. So I guess I will have to call something like `GoToState` or `GoToElementState` in code behind.

However, `ExtendedVisualStateManager` doesn't seem to exist in **WinRT**. I tried using

```
VisualStateManager.GetCustomVisualStateManager(this.LayoutRoot)
```

but it always returns `null`.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just figured this out.

First create a helper class just like how we used to use it in Silverlight or Windows Phone (I took this piece of code from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/02daf089-4f3e-4fcb-959d-499861a77fe4/how-to-extendedvisualstatemanagersetusefluidlayout-?forum=blend) and modified it a little bit so when an element doesn't have any visual state groups attached, it automatically goes search for its parent until it finds any).

```
public class ExtendedVisualStateManager : VisualStateManager
{
    protected override bool GoToStateCore(Control control, FrameworkElement stateGroupsRoot, string stateName, VisualStateGroup group, VisualState state, bool useTransitions)
    {
        if ((group == null) || (state == null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (control == null)
        {
            control = new ContentControl();
        }

        return base.GoToStateCore(control, stateGroupsRoot, stateName, group, state, useTransitions);
    }

    public static bool GoToElementState(FrameworkElement element, string stateName, bool useTransitions)
    {
        var root = FindNearestStatefulFrameworkElement(element);

        var customVisualStateManager = VisualStateManager.GetCustomVisualStateManager(root) as ExtendedVisualStateManager;

        return ((customVisualStateManager != null) && customVisualStateManager.GoToStateInternal(root, stateName, useTransitions));
    }

    private static FrameworkElement FindNearestStatefulFrameworkElement(FrameworkElement element)
    {
        while (element != null && VisualStateManager.GetCustomVisualStateManager(element) == null)
        {
            element = element.Parent as FrameworkElement;
        }

        return element;
    }

    private bool GoToStateInternal(FrameworkElement stateGroupsRoot, string stateName, bool useTransitions)
    {
        VisualStateGroup group;
        VisualState state;

        return (TryGetState(stateGroupsRoot, stateName, out group, out state) && this.GoToStateCore(null, stateGroupsRoot, stateName, group, state, useTransitions));
    }

    private static bool TryGetState(FrameworkElement element, string stateName, out VisualStateGroup group, out VisualState state)
    {
        group = null;
        state = null;

        foreach (VisualStateGroup group2 in VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(element))
        {
            foreach (VisualState state2 in group2.States)
            {
                if (state2.Name == stateName)
                {
                    group = group2;
                    state = state2;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you will need to manually update the xaml to something like this -

```
<VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
    <common:ExtendedVisualStateManager />
</VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup .../>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

I guess the good thing about this solution is that you can still see the **visual states** in Blend's **States** tab, for Blend lovers this is just cool.

Answer (score 0):

Typically I have a single `UpdateVisualState(bool useTransitions)` method in my controls that makes all the `GoToVisualState()` calls. If something can't be animated then I see two options:

1. Make the change in code behind in my `UpdateVisualState()` method. The drawback of this solutions is that Blend will not show the change in the visual state editor. I don't personally care though because I rarely use Blend on already integrated designs and this solution is simple.
2. Create a(n attached) property or behavior that makes the expected change and animate that property from the visual state `Storyboard`. That's a bit more work, but could keep Blend support in your project.

Comment: The first method would work if the element that contains the visual states is a type of `Control`; if it's a `Grid` or something that doesn't inherit from `Control`, you will need to use the `ExtendedVisualStateManager` or something similar.

The second way would work but then you lose all the transitions between visual states.

Comment: Not really, if you use either of these methods - you are basically writing code, so you can do anything you want in there - run Storyboard animations, per frame animations and even animate non-animatable properties like `Grid.ColumnDefinitions` etc.

Comment: Yes, anything can be done thru code, but in this case both solutions are not ideal 'cause you'd end up writing a lot of extra code which can be automatically generated in visual states manager. For example, you never need to write storyboards to go from a particular state back to the normal state. `VisualStateManager` does this for you.

Comment: I didn't say do not use VSM, I meant you could use both, though the `CustomVisualStateManager` does indeed sound like the best solution.

Comment: This isn't working for me on WinRT. I copied the extended vsm and updated the XAML as the answer suggested. However, no update takes place. Specifically, I'm using a grid control. I use the following call: ExtendedVisualStateManager.GoToElementState(grid, "InitializedState", useTransitions: true);

Comment: Try passing the control instead of the grid - e.g. `VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(this, "InitializedState", true);`