# How can I implement a Multi-DataTriggerBehavior

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, expression-blend

How can I implement a Multi-DataTriggerBehavior?

I already have one DataTriggerBehavior in place. But I need a trigger that is based on an event and multiple conditions.

Comment: By 'multiple conditions' you mean property changes right?

Comment: Yes. I mean trigger an action based on the value of multiple properties.

Comment: Sounds like you need to create your own behavior to handle this. Just create a bunch of dependency properties and subscribe to their property changed callbacks. If all the callbacks are called, do something.

Comment: Well, I get stuck when I all conditions are satisfied and I want to invoke a VisualState programmatically. Because my grid owns a VisualStateGroup, I am unable to perform a successful visual state change within a behavior class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you to create your own `Behavior` to handle this.

These are the steps for a possible solution.

1. Because you will need to somehow invoke a `VisualState` in your `Behavior`'s code behind, you have to change the `VisualStateManager` defined in your xaml to `ExtendedVisualStateManager` (see the implementation in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23697204/go-to-visual-states-inside-a-grid-in-code-behind-in-windows-store-apps)) as the built-in `VisualStateManager`'s `GoToState` method doesn't accept `Grid` as its parameter.
2. Create a `Behavior` and attach it to a proper `Control`. I assume you want to do something when an **event** of the `Control` is raised. So you need to create a handler for this in your `Behavior` code-behind.
3. Create dependency properties that map the properties defined in your viewmodel and subscribe to all their property changed `callbacks`. You might need local flags to tell whether all of them are updated or not. If they are, in your event handler, call `ExtendedVisualStateManager.GoToElementState`. Note that you might also need to create a dependency property to reference your `Grid` and a few others to map your `VisualState` names.
4. Attach the `Behavior` to your `Control` in xaml and data-bind all its dependency properties.

Hope this makes sense.