# Goto VisualState in Listivew item DateTemplate windows phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, visualstatemanager

My requirement: when tapped on the border in ListViewItem(DataTemplate) an overlay should appear on top of it with animation.

In my listview data template I defined a visual state at the root. I want to goto the visual state when user taps on the border. I have tried following xaml but it is not working

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
        <Grid Background="{Binding ItemBackground}"
          Margin="0,0,0,5" Height="auto">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup >
                    <VisualState x:Name="OverlayState">
                        <Storyboard >
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="checkedBorder"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 Duration="0"
                                                 To="1" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

            <Grid Height="auto" Margin="14,0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="110"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="55"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <!--Image Section" -->
                <Grid Height="108" Margin="0,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Grid Margin="0">
                        <Border HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="98" Height="98" CacheMode="BitmapCache" CornerRadius="30">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ImageSource}"  Stretch="Fill"></ImageBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <icore:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                                    <icore:GoToStateAction StateName="OverlayState" TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=checkedBorder}"></icore:GoToStateAction>
                                </icore:EventTriggerBehavior>
                            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        </Border>

                        <!-- Overlay Border -->
                        <Border HorizontalAlignment="Left" Opacity="0" x:Name="checkedBorder" Margin="0" Background="#99000000" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"                                 
                            Width="98" Height="98" CacheMode="BitmapCache" CornerRadius="30">
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Where/how do you call GoToVisualState?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is more complex than I initially thought.

First, let's correct a few issues in your xaml code.

1. The following line needs to be removed. It's like saying 'go find a state named `OverlayState` on the `checkedBorder` element'. Clearly that state is not on that element. Also, changing the `ElementName` binding to point to the top level `Grid` (where the visual state group is) won't work either, I will explain why later.

`TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=checkedBorder}"`

2. You should always give your `VisualStateGroup` a *name*, like this -

`<VisualStateGroup x:Name="MyStates">`

3. You need to set `IsHitTestVisible` to `False` on your overlay `Border`, otherwise the `Border` with image background will not be able to receive the `Tapped` event because it's sitting behind the overlay one.

I thought it should be good to go. However, if you run the app now, you will get an unhandled exception saying

> Target  does not define any VisualStateGroups.

If you add back the `TargetObject` `ElementName` binding and change it to point to the top level `Grid`, the exception will go away but the visual state is not called.

`TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=myFirstLevelGridWhereTheVSGroupIs}"`

**This is because a normal `VisualStateManager` only works for `Control`s not `FrameworkElement`s since your `Grid` is not a type of `Control`.**

In a WP Silverlight app, it's fairly simple to fix. All you need to do is to add a built-in `CustomVisualStateManager` which allows you to pass in a `FrameworkElement` on top of the `VisualStateGroups` definition. But such class doesn't exist in WinRT.

I asked a question about this a while ago and eventually came up with an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23697204/go-to-visual-states-inside-a-grid-in-code-behind-in-windows-store-apps).

Include this class into your project, and add the reference in your xaml code, just before your `VisualStateGroups` definition.

```
<VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
    <local:ExtendedVisualStateManager />
</VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>

<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="MyStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="OverlayState">
```

Lastly, because unlike the `GoToStateAction` in Silverlight app, the WinRT's `GoToStateAction` doesn't handle `CustomVisualStateManager`, you will have to create a custom `GoToStateAction` too.

```
public class ExtendedGoToStateAction : DependencyObject, IAction
{
    public string StateName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(StateNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StateNameProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StateNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("StateName", typeof(string), typeof(ExtendedGoToStateAction), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public bool UseTransitions
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(UseTransitionsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UseTransitionsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty UseTransitionsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("UseTransitions", typeof(bool), typeof(ExtendedGoToStateAction), new PropertyMetadata(false));     

    public object Execute(object sender, object parameter)
    {
        return ExtendedVisualStateManager.GoToElementState((FrameworkElement)sender, this.StateName, this.UseTransitions);
    }
}
```

And replace the built-in one with this.

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <iCore:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
        <local:ExtendedGoToStateAction StateName="OverlayState"/>
    </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
```

You should be able to see the animation working now. :)

Comment: Many thanks Justin XL, by following you detailed explanation I was able to use animate object with in list view item. But now I have to use customized toggle button to achieve the result because the list view item selection transition :(. On my object I do not want that list selection transition should execute but because it is a not a control so list view selection transition executes every time when my object is tapped. Previously I avoid toggle button because of the optimization as toggle button will generate more xaml and will take more space.

Comment: No worries. :) I think you should be able to remove the default listboxitem's transitions by modifying the `ItemContainerStyle` of the listview.

Comment: yes, But I want to keep the transition for other controls in the list item

Comment: Oh I see. Make sense. I think a custom toggle is a good alternative here given what you want to achieve as it also prevents the listviewitem from receiving the tap event.